# Sum of product of combinations of a set

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

I'm trying to get the following sum in terms of `n`, where the brackets represent `nCr` of combination theory.

$$
S = \sum_{x=0}^n\sum_{y=0}^{n-x}\sum_{z=0}^{n-x-y}
\begin{pmatrix}
n \\
x \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
n-x \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
n-x-y \\
z \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

By simple combination logic, I'm expecting `S` to be `3^n`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have made corrections.

Comment: The sum would be $4^n$, wouldn't it?  This can be seen with repeated application of the binomial theorem.  Rearrange things as $\sum\limits_{x=0}^n\sum\limits_{y=0}^{n-x}\binom{n}{x}\binom{n-x}{y}\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{z=0}^{n-x-y}\binom{n-x-y}{z}}$ and simplify what I've colored blue to be $2^{n-x-y}$ as per the binomial theorem.  Then do the same for the next, $\sum\limits_{x=0}^n\binom{n}{x}\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{y=0}^{n-x}\binom{n-x}{y}2^{n-x-y}}$ and simplify what is blue to be $3^{n-x}$ again via binomial theorem.  One final application will give $4^n$

Answer (score 3):

JMoravitz is correct in his comment.

---

You can rewrite the summation as:$$\sum_{x+y+z+u=n}\frac{n!}{x!y!z!u!}$$where $x,y,z,u$ are nonnegative integers.

In this we can recognize the number of ways the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ can be split up in $4$ covering disjoint and distinguishable subsets.

Approaching this differently we can say that for each of the elements of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ there are $4$ options, leading to $4^n$ possibilities.

Comment: What are "distinguishable subsets"?

Comment: You start with names $A,B,C,D$
for $4$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Then to be counted must be the possible *tuples* $(A,B,C,D)$ under the condition that the sets are disjoint and covering. The fact that I ask for tuples (so with an order) instead of e.g. sets $\{A,B,C,D\}$ corresponds with distinguishable.

Comment: OK, so this expression is the number of partitions of a set of size $n$ into 4 (possibly empty) subsets. I agree.

Comment: The word "partition" is not on its place in your comment. Firstly because elements of partitions are not empty and secondly by partitions we are *not* dealing with tuples. E.g. $\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\}\}$ counts for only one partition of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. By tuples things change because $(\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\})\neq (\{3\},\{1,2\},\{4\},\{5\})$

Comment: Right, this leads us to the statement I intended to post : this is the number of functions from a set with $n$ elements to a set with 4 elements.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For every element of the domain there are $4$ candidates as outcome, so there are $4^n$ functions. If the codomain is $\{1,2,3,4\}$ then the sets $A,B,C,D$ can be taken to be the preimages $f^{-1}(\{1\}),f^{-1}(\{2\}),f^{-1}(\{3\}),f^{-1}(\{4\})$.

Comment: If this is in your view a proper answer to your question then do not hesitate to accept it.

Comment: Only Penguin can accept the answer. But yes, you deserve an upvote. ;)

Comment: @OlivierRoche Oh,...I wasn't aware of it that it was not the OP that I was talking to. Thank you for your upvote.

Comment: Isn't it that each of the elements `{1, ..., n}` have 3 options, not 4. Since `u = n - x - y - z`. If this is correct, the answer becomes `3^n`.

Comment: Try it out on $n=1$. There are $4$ options. One of the variables  $x,y,z,u$ takes value  $1$ and the others take value  $0$.